# ERROR Error: No provider for Router! Angular4

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm trying Firebase OAuth Login With Custom Firestore User Data tutorial from angularfirebase.com and I am having an error.

In the core.module I have **providers: [AuthService]** and I tried putting inside a component's constructor itself still the same error.

```
    AppComponent.html:15 ERROR Error: No provider for Router!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9492)
    at _createClass (core.es5.js:9533)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9503)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9488)
View_AppComponent_0 @   AppComponent.html:15
```

In app.component at line 15 I have :

```
<app-user-profile></app-user-profile>
```

Here is my user-profile html:

```
    <div *ngIf="auth.user | async; then authenticated else guest">
    <!-- template will replace this div -->
</div>


<!-- NOT logged in -->
<ng-template #guest>
<p>Login to get started...</p>

<button (click)="auth.googleLogin()">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i> Connect Google
</button>

</ng-template>


<!-- Logged in -->
<ng-template #authenticated>
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
    <h3>Name: {{ user.displayName }}</h3>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

*user-profile.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And this is my auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'

interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  favoriteColor?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {


      this.user = this.afAuth.authState
        .switchMap(user => {
          if (user) {
            return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
          } else {
            return Observable.of(null)
          }
        })
  }



  googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }

  private oAuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((credential) => {
        this.updateUserData(credential.user)
      })
  }


  private updateUserData(user) {


    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

    const data: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    }

    return userRef.set(data)

  }



}
```

And I have imported **RouterModule** in app.module.ts

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';


import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './layout/header/header.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './layout/menu/menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './layout/footer/footer.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    UserProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    CoreModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {



  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(){


  }



}
```

Comment: You're not using in your service, why would you keep the dependency here ?

Comment: import RouterModule in core.module.ts too, your service is a part of core.module

Comment: @FatehMohamed did this, no change

Comment: Can you post your `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts`

Comment: @TonyRoczz did that.

Comment: Have you tried adding `AuthService` inside providers array in `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: @TonyRoczz I did this right now, didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must import `RouterModule.forRoot([])` in the root of your application.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jmdem)

Answer (score 0):

You said you included the AuthService in your providers, but in your example it seems to be empty?

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    CoreModule

  ],
  providers: [], <----- put the AuthService there
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

EDIT: Sorry, I just had seen the comments. Sometimes I had a similar problem, that some services couldn't be recognized, when I still had a running instance of my application running. Sometimes then it helped shutting it down and re-build it.

Also, it complains about a router not found? Maybe you should add in your imports something like this...

```
imports: [
    ...
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'no-access', component: NoAccessComponent }
    ]),
```

Comment: I didn't updated the code here, but I did that and still doesn't work